# Errors occurred with vimeo player on my Durandal page

Tags: javascript, video, durandal, vimeo

I work on a Durandal project. I display a video from http://vimeo.com on my page like this:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/48502577?portrait=0&color=ffffff" width="480" height="256" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Something very basic as suggested on the vimeo website.

**The problem (only with IE): whenever I navigate (too quickly) to another page of my Durandal project** I got an error like: `Object doesn't support this action` from http://livepassdl.conviva.com/ver/2.72.0.13589/LivePass.js

By `too quickly` I mean as soon as my page is displayed I click on another button menu to navigate away and I suspect the vimeo video don't finished initializing then an error occurred.

The problem don't occurred if I wait 2 or 3 seconds after the page displayed before navigate away.

This problem don't happened outside of a Durandal project.

Any idea how to prevent such errors?

Please pay attention that I don't cache views like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid page-host">
    <!--ko router: { cacheViews:false }--><!--/ko-->
</div>
```

If I turn this cacheViews parameter to on, then the problem don't occurs but I don't want to cache my views for other reasons.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

- in a basic Durandal project insert the iframe code above then navigate to this page and immediately navigate to another page of your Durandal project. >> an error occured.

PS: I don't have this kind of problems with videos comes from YouTube or Dailymotion, ...

Thanks.